# Django GenericRelation in model Mixin

Tags: django, generic-relations

I have mixin and model:

```
class Mixin(object):
    field = GenericRelation('ModelWithGR')

class MyModel(Mixin, models.Model):
   ...
```

But django do not turn `GenericRelation` field into `GenericRelatedObjectManager`:

```
>>> m = MyModel()
>>> m.field
<django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericRelation>
```

When I put field into model itself or abstract model - it works fine:

```
class MyModel(Mixin, models.Model):
   field = GenericRelation('ModelWithGR')

>>> m = MyModel()
>>> m.field
<django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericRelatedObjectManager at 0x3bf47d0>
```

How can I use `GenericRelation` in mixin?

Comment: Could something like this help? http://timmyomahony.com/blog/reversing-unique-generic-foreign-key-django/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always inherit from `Model` and make it abstract instead of inheriting it from `object`. Python's mro will figure everything out.
Like so:

```
class Mixin(models.Model):
    field = GenericRelation('ModelWithGR')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class MyModel(Mixin, models.Model):
    ...
```

Comment: I know. In question I wrote 'When I put field into model itself or __abstract model__ - it works fine'. The question is about mixin only.

Comment: You cannot use fields on regular objects in the same way they are used on Models, especially related ones. All because there is special logic applied upon model class creation, which deals with fields attached to it in special ways, depending on a field type:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L60
You can try to figure something out, but without some weird hacks it won't be possible. So I wouldn't even recommend doing that.